# Changing value of a generic type node in a doubly linked list

Tags: java, generics, doubly-linked-list

I'm working on an exercise where I want to make a method that changes the value of a node, after checking if it's in the list of elements. I've tried doing this by creating a new object, newNode, and using the setter methods from the node class to change the value, but I'm not getting anywhere. How should I approach this problem in order to understand it better. Thanks.

Linked List Class:

```
public class DLList<E> implements DLListADT<E> {

private DLNode<E> front; //. This is a reference to the first node of the doubly linked list.
private DLNode<E> rear; //. This is a reference to the last node of the doubly linked list.
private int count; //. The value of this variable is the number of data items in the linked list

public DLList() { // Creates an empty list.
    front = null;
    rear = null;
    count = 0;


    /** Changes the value of dataItem to newValue. An InvalidDataItemException is thrown if the given dataItem is not in the list. */

public void changeValue (E dataItem, int newValue) throws InvalidDataItemException {

        if (front == null) {
            throw new InvalidDataItemException("The specified element is not in the priority queue");

        DLNode<E> newNode = new DLNode<E>(dataItem, newValue);
        newNode.setData(dataItem);
        newNode.setValue(newValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure what you want to do is to go through your linked list until you find a matching node and modify that node

```
DLNode<E> newNode == front;
while(newNode.getNext() != null){
    newNode = newNode.getNext();
    if(newNode.getData().equals(dataItem)){
        newNode.setValue(newValue);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be working! How would you recommend implementing the throw exception into the method. I tried adding an else clause after the if statement, and that just results in the else clause being called everytime.

Comment: create a `boolean exists = false` before your while loop.  In your if statement, put `exists= true` before `break;`.  Then after the while loop, do `if(!exists){//throw exception}`